# Flexbox and Flex Wrap issues on different devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I am trying to get the following layout to work using flexbox, I have two div containers next to each other. In the first div there are 6 boxes they must be 3, then wrap on to the next line. The second div contains text. I have tried a number of different approaches as I would like them all stacked on mobile and tablet and then laid out above on desktop.

Code I have so far:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="child">Test</div>
  <div class="child">Test</div>
  <div class="child">Test</div>
  <div class="child">Test</div>
  <div class="child">Test</div>
  <div class="child">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="box-container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box-container{
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two containers are made to be next to each other by setting `flex-basis: 50%` so that they each take up 50% of the row and by making their container (`body`) a flex container.

A media query is used to change the style when the maximum width of the screen is 768px or lower. It changes the the `flex-direction` of the containers to `column` so that elements are stack vertically. Then, `flex-basis` is set to 100% so each element takes up an entire column.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-basis: 50%;

    border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 20px);
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    .child {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .box-container {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
        <h1>
            hello
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for that will that also sort out the two divs? As I cant seem to get them next to each other despite using display:flex on each of the containers?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I did not understand how you want `box-container` to be positioned relative to `container`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I would like it so that on mobile and tablet its stacked and then on desktop they are next to each other. Thank you.